# Is it possible to record a user's screen without Java, Flash, or some third-party install?

Tags: html, google-chrome, webkit

Is it possible to enable users to record their screen (with their permission) without resorting to Flash or Java?

This is needed for Webkit browsers.

Comment: How is flash not a browser plugin ?

Comment: Java is a browser plugin as well

Comment: Sorry, I need to remove that line about plug-ins.